# How to align text within a div separated by a divider

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

So I was trying out the angular material divider for my side project and I've encountered some problems with aligning the text

[image]

As you can see from the picture the text on the right side instead of placed beside the vertical line, is placed under both the vertical line and the left side text.

HTML Code:

```
<section class="about" id="about">
<div class="content">
    <div class="titleContent">
        <h2> Title Here </h2>
    </div>
    <mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
    <div class="textContent">
        <p> Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum
            Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum
            Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum Lorep Ipsum
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
section{
    padding: 30px 50px;
}

.about{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.about .content{
    min-width: 800px;
}

.about .content mat-divider{
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    position: inherit !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.about .content .titleContent > h2{
    max-width: 200px;
}

.about .content .titleContent{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.about .content .textContent{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I tried to align while modifying using google chrome but it didn't work since I have little to no knowledge of how front-end things work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give display flex to the .content class

```
 .content{
   display:flex;
 }
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, though i don't understand why it worked. Is there anything wrong in my code that by adding that it just works?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code, the thing is that the div tag occupy all the available space horizontally by default, by  using flex , you can align many divs on the same line